# How to apply the styles for Kendo treeview parent node only

Tags: css, kendo-treeview

I have kendo tree-view in my application,I want to apply the styles for kendo tree-view parent node only.How to apply the styles like Font weight-bold for the parent node of tree-view?
My treeview code is

```
var tree= $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  checkboxes: {
    checkChildren: true
  },
  dataSource: [{        
     id: 2, text: "select all", expanded: true,
     items: [
        { id: 3, text: "ABH" },
        { id: 4, text: "VFG" },
        { id: 5, text: "VFGT" },
        { id: 6, text: "GTYUJ" },
        { id: 7, text: "GHJ" }
     ]
   }]
 }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/85/).

Comment: Broken English, horrible code indentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to configure this in scripts.

```
  .k-top.k-bot {font-weight: bold;}
```